# Webflow how to display error messages in this case?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm struggling with setting up validation for my Spring WebFlow. The validation works fine, but I can't make error messages appear. The flow succesfully binds to order.customer model ( and sets its fields) but nothing more. I don't think that I should manually catch validation exception too, but if I don't do that, flow crashes. I'm also using hibernate validator besides basic jsr-303 validation.Also I would like to validate form without trying to save it to database first.
here are the flows:
checkout-flow.xml

```
<subflow-state id="customer" subflow="checkout/customer">
      <input name="order" value="order"/>
      <transition on="customerReady" to="updateCustomerAddress" />
    </subflow-state>

    <action-state id="updateCustomerAddress">
        <evaluate expression="customerServiceImpl.updateAddressDetails(order.customer)" />
        <transition to="customer"
            on-exception="javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException" />
        <transition to="orderConfirmation" />   
    </action-state>
```

customer-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <input name="order" required="true"/>   

    <view-state id="collectCustomerInfo" view="collectCustomerInfo.jsp" model="order">
        <transition on="customerInfoCollected" to="customerReady" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancel"/>
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="cancel" />
    <end-state id="customerReady" />

</flow>
```

collectCustomerInfo.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Customer</h1>
                <p>Customer details</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container">
        <form:form modelAttribute="order.customer" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Customer Details</legend>

                <form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-danger" element="div"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="name"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.name.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <form:input id="name" path="name" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="surname"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.surname.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <form:input id="surname" path="surname" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                        <form:errors path="surname" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="streetName"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.streetName.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="streetName" path="streetName" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="streetName" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="doorNo"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.doorNo.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="doorNo" path="doorNo" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="doorNo" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="zipCode"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.zipCode.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="zipCode" path="zipCode" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="zipCode" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="areaName"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.areaName.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="areaName" path="areaName" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="areaName" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="state"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.state.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="state" path="state" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="state" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="country"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.country.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="country" path="country" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="country" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="phoneNumber"><spring:message code="editCustomer.form.phoneNumber.label"/></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="form:input-prepend">
                            <form:input id="phoneNumber" path="phoneNumber" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                            <form:errors path="phoneNumber" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary"
                            value="Add" name="_eventId_customerInfoCollected" />
                        <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default" name="_eventId_cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form:form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7565769627033046336L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CustomerID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer customerId;
    @Email
    @Column(name = "Email", nullable = false, length = 60)
    //can not duplicate emails in database
    @CustomerEmail
    @Size(min = 3, max = 60, message = "{Size.Customer.email.validation}")
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false, length = 60)
    @Size(min = 5, max = 60, message = "{Size.Customer.password.validation}")
    private String password;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "{Size.Customer.name.validation}")
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 30)
    private String name;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "{Size.Customer.surname.validation}")
    @Column(name = "Surname", length = 30)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "StreetName", length = 50)
    private String streetName;
    @Column(name = "DoorNo")
    private String doorNo;
    @Column(name = "AreaName", length = 20)
    private String areaName;
    @Column(name = "State", length = 50)
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "Country", length = 25)
    private String country;
    @Column(name = "ZipCode", length = 10)
    private String zipCode;
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{9})") 
    @Column(name = "PhoneNumber", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String phoneNumber;
```

Any tips how this should be done the right way?

Comment: Have you read the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/views.html#view-validation-jsr303).

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, however I can't get it to work

Comment: What isn't working.. Show your configuration not only the flow. And add your order object. For nested objects you need to have `@Valid` on the nested field, else validation will not propagate to nested objects.

Comment: @M.Deinum where can I insert valid annotation? I don't use any controllers for this. Thanks for the effort

Comment: @M.Deinum I added valid annotation in Order class, for Customer field. That solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: @M.Deinum do have any idea how to exclude single field from binding in nested class? I use valid Customer class and i want to exclude customer.email from binding
I'm afraid <binder> tag doesn't work for nested fields :(

Comment: Have you actually tried the tag? (This is actually a completely different question as the validation one). BUt something like `binder property="customer.email"` should work I guess.

Comment: I want to exclude email from validation.I tried this
<binder>
        <binding property="customer.name" required="true" />
 //rest of fields in same manner
    </binder>
But it won't let me go past validation because of email constraint

Comment: Do you want to exclude it from validation or binding? You are using JSR-303 so that will always be invoked. Unless you attach it to a validation group and validate all but that validation group. But binding and validation are different things.

Comment: I just want to ignore customer email validation for this flow, I need to have email constraint for registering new users. When I launch the flow, hibernate reads customer data from database (along with email). I don't really know what can I do with it without changing so much code. I might give up on validation :/

Comment: If the emailadress is there already from the database, then what is the issue? It is already there, if you disable binding nothing will be updated. Validation will still be done, but it will always succeed because it is there.

Comment: @M.Deinum validation for emails checks if given email exists in database. If it already exists, validation fails ( you can't create a new account if there's one already created for that email) I used this validation in registration form.
I'd need to have 2 separate validation constraints,one for registering and one for orders. But I don't really need to check that in flow, because I've set webflow to allow only logged in users to the flow.

Comment: I think I need to set up some validation groups, thanks for the help mate
@M.Deinum

Comment: @M.Deinum I managed to make this work the way I want it to,
email is now annotated with @CustomerEmail(groups = ValidateOnCreationOnly.class) 
That interface extends Default group. Now I validate order using default group and validate registration using validateOnCreationOnly interface(which is default + CustomerEmail). You helped me with two problems in one thread, thanks a lot. You can add answer to this thread so i can accept it. Have a nice day :)